# Compile standalone application using qt with cygwin's compiler

Tags: c++, windows, qt, gcc, cygwin

I used cygwin to compile static libs and installed it. This is libs can be compilling with mingw too, but this is hardcoreway. I can compile my code using cygwin bash, but this exe using cygwin1.dll and cant be standalone. 
So, im trying to compile standalone exe with QT using MINGW with this libs. I think , i can use for this cygwin's compiler, but i cant find any information about it.

After compiling i have this errors :

error: undefined reference to ctime_r
error: undefined reference to __xpg_strerror_r'

Im using QT5 on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you built the libraries with one compiler tool chain (cygwin) and now you want to build the application with a different tool chain (mingw). This generally won't work. The object files and static libraries created by different tool chains often can't be linked together. Technically they have different Application Binary Interfaces (ABIs).  The MinGw site has a pretty good and detailed explanation of this,  [Interoperability of Libraries Created by Different Compiler Brands](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Interoperability_of_Libraries_Created_by_Different_Compiler_Brands).

Comment: Thanks for answer.
Is there a way to make a friend QT Creator and Cygwin's g++?